# Error while trying to sign archive

Tags: gradle, android-gradle-plugin

I am trying to sign and release an library to sonatype nexus, got my keys but when I try to run:

```
gradle signArchives
```

I get:

```
Could not evaluate onlyIf predicate for task ...
```

The error seems to be triggered by the existence of the file `gradle.properties` in `/home/[user]/.gradle`. Without this file and it's content the sign tasks just gets skipped.

Using gradle 1.8 on ubuntu 12.04

Anybody sen this behavior before?

Answer (score 3):

The issue was with a the gnupg keys. I had to regenerate them, push the public key again to the server and update `$HOME/.gradle/gradle.properties`